# gitlab-pages and custom domain

Tags: nginx, gitlab, custom-domain, gitlab-pages

## gitlab

create the folder in the host for gitlab container :

```bash
sudo mkdir -p \
/srv/gitlab/conf \
/srv/gitlab/log \
/srv/gitlab/data \
/srv/gitlab-runner/conf
```

gitlab container docker compose file :

```yaml
volumes:
  gitlab_conf:
    name: gitlab-conf
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/gitlab/conf

  gitlab_log:
    name: gitlab-log
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/gitlab/log

  gitlab_data:
    name: gitlab-data
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/gitlab/data

  gitlab_ssl:
    name: gitlab-ssl
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /etc/letsencrypt
  
  gitlab_runner_conf:
    name: gitlab-runner-conf
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/gitlab-runner/conf

networks:
  gitlab_network:
    name: gitlab-network
  # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/index.html#custom-domains-with-tls-support
  # Custom domains with TLS support
  # Requirements: Secondary IP
  gitlab_pages_network:
    name: gitlab-pages-network

services:
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab-container
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - gitlab_conf:/etc/gitlab
      - gitlab_log:/var/log/gitlab
      - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - gitlab_ssl:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - gitlab_network
      - gitlab_pages_network
    ports:
      - 22:22
    shm_size: 256m
  gitlab_runner:
    container_name: gitlab-runner-container
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - gitlab_runner_conf:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - gitlab_network
```

```bash
sudo docker compose -p gitlab -f ./gitlab-docker-compose.yml up -d
```

config gitlab.rb :

```bash
sudo openssl dhparam -out /srv/gitlab/conf/dhparam.pem 2048
```

```bash
sudo cp /srv/gitlab/conf/gitlab.rb /srv/gitlab/conf/gitlab.rb.orig
sudo rm /srv/gitlab/conf/gitlab.rb
```

```bash
sudo nano /srv/gitlab/conf/gitlab.rb
```

```rb
### GITLAB
external_url 'https://gitlab.freec0ding.dev'

gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'freec0ding.dev'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22

nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['listen_https'] = true
nginx['listen_port'] = 4431
nginx['ssl_dhparam'] = '/etc/gitlab/dhparam.pem'
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/fullchain.pem'
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/privkey.pem'
nginx['ssl_trusted_certificate'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/chain.pem'

### GITLAB-PAGES
pages_external_url 'https://pages.freec0ding.dev'

pages_nginx['enable'] = true
pages_nginx['listen_https'] = true
pages_nginx['listen_port'] = 4432
pages_nginx['ssl_dhparam'] = '/etc/gitlab/dhparam.pem'
pages_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/fullchain.pem'
pages_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/privkey.pem'
pages_nginx['ssl_trusted_certificate'] = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/chain.pem'
```

```bash
sudo docker exec gitlab-container gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

use nginx as reverse proxy :

create the folder in the host for nginx container :

```bash
sudo mkdir -p \
/srv/web/nginx/conf \
/srv/web/nginx/log \
/srv/web/www-data
```

nginx container docker compose file :

```yaml
volumes:
  nginx_conf:
    name: nginx-conf
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/web/nginx/conf

  nginx_log:
    name: nginx-log
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/web/nginx/log
  
  nginx_ssl:
    name: nginx-ssl
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /etc/letsencrypt

  www_data:
    name: www-data
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/web/www-data

networks:
  web_network:
    name: web-network
  gitlab_network:
    name: gitlab-network
    external: true

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx-container
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nginx_conf:/etc/nginx
      - nginx_log:/var/log/nginx
      - nginx_ssl:/etc/letsencrypt
      - www_data:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - web_network
      - gitlab_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

```bash
sudo docker compose -p web -f ./web-docker-compose.yml up -d
```

conf files for nginx :

nginx gitlab.conf :

```
### GITLAB

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name gitlab.freec0ding.dev;

  server_tokens off;
  
  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name gitlab.freec0ding.dev;
  
  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/chain.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_cache off;

    proxy_pass https://gitlab:4431;
  }
}
```

nginx gitlab-pages.conf :

```
### GITLAB-PAGES

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name pages.freec0ding.dev;

  server_tokens off;
  
  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_error.log;

  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name pages.freec0ding.dev;
  
  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/chain.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_cache off;

    proxy_pass https://gitlab:4432;
  }
}
```

nginx gitlab-pages-wildcard.conf :

```
### GITLAB-PAGES-WILDCARD

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name *.pages.freec0ding.dev;

  server_tokens off;
  
  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_error.log;

  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name *.pages.freec0ding.dev;
  
  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/freec0ding.dev/chain.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_pages_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_cache off;

    proxy_pass https://gitlab:4432;
  }
}
```

```bash
sudo docker exec nginx-container service nginx restart
```

after create the project with **Pages/Hugo** template :

```bash
export RUNNER_TOKEN='XXXXX' && \
sudo -E docker exec -it gitlab-runner-container gitlab-runner register \
--non-interactive \
--url https://gitlab.freec0ding.dev \
--token ${RUNNER_TOKEN} \
--executor "docker" \
--docker-image alpine:latest \
--description "runner"
```

now I have my hugo page project on https://sysc4ll.pages.freec0ding.dev/www/

I would like to have this page on the url : https://www.sysc4ll.sh

What I have to do ? Please